# M-x-helm Interfering with sql-sqlite

Tags: helm

I love helm and try to utilize it whenever possible.  Naturally, I have bound <kbd>M-x</kbd> to `M-x-helm`.  For the most part, this has not caused any problems for me.  However, I have noticed that it appears to be interfering with `sql-sqlite`.

When I try to execute this command, it prompts me for the path to the sqlite database.  Normally, helm allows me to traverse the directory structure and find the file I would like.  But when it comes to `sql-sqlite`, it limits me to the files in the current directory.  If I try to manually type in the path, I just get the error "No Match".

If I instead run `execute-extended-command`, I am able to navigate to the appropriate path and proceed without issue.

Has anyone else experienced this problem before, or have recommendations on how to address / debug it?

I'm not sure that it matters, but [here is my configuration](https://github.com/keelerm84/.emacs.d) and a link to the [relevant helm setup](https://github.com/keelerm84/.emacs.d/blob/master/customizations/setup-helm.el).

Comment: This does not address your issue, but you can turn of helm completion for sql-sqlite exclusively by customizing `helm-completing-read-handlers-alist`

Comment: Are you sure `sql-sqlite` is not rebinding your `M-x` key to something else ? Try checking that with `C-h k M-x`

Comment: I'm not sure that I'm duplicating your problem exactly, but here's what I've found: when I'm prompted for the path to the database, the usual helm commands for navigating directories (`C-l`, `C-j`, etc) don't work *until* I hit backspace.  After that, I can navigate using the usual commands just fine.  Perhaps that will be a good workaround.

Comment: Looks like I'm not the only one having this problem.  https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/issues/707